# Why can't Excel calculate (-1)^10,000,000,000?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Why can't Excel calculate -1 to the 10,000,000,000 power?  I get an #NUM! error when I tried to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's too "big," the [iteration limit's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) 32,767, so trying 10 billion is too much.

Or it could be that Excel's trying to expand it first, in which case it's hitting the "Arguments in a function" limit of 255. Or maybe the "Size of the operand stack" limit of 1,024. There's lots of limits in Excel that are less than 10 billion.

Even `bc` doesn't like trying that:

```
(-1)^10000000000
Runtime error (func=(main), adr=16): exponent too large in raise
```

But, LibreOffice Calc has no problem with it. In fact, it's good up to about `=(-1)^1.79769313486232E+307` or `=(-1)^1E+308` (to the power of 1 plus 308 zeros).

---

Why are you trying to do that anyway? 10 billion is even, so the answer's 1.

Comment: I knew the answer obviously.  I'm merely testing the limits of Excel's computational capabilities.  Thank you for the answer.

Comment: The documented Iterations limit of 32,767 does not really seem to be the limiting factor here. I was able to calculate (-1)^(2^32-2) in Excel. (-1)^(2^32-1) fails.

Comment: Yes, the limit seems to be 4,294,967,294 times.  (2^32 = 4,294,967,296).  Interestingly, if you add digits to the right of the decimal point, it works up to a point but seems to drop those digits after the calculation is done.

Comment: The dropping digits could be the 15-digit Number precision limit... but Excel isn't open-source so it's really hard to tell exactly what goes wrong. Interestingly I just noticed the Largest allowed positive number & 
number via formula are ~9E+307 and ~1e+308 which lines up with the LibreOffice tests, or they might do some simplifications first

Comment: `-1` seems to be a peculiar case though. It can calculate n^(10^10) for 0 < n < 1. It will even calculate it for cases where the outcome is less than that 1E308 value limit, like 1.00000007.